# Hex editing GBA in C++

Tags: c++, hex, game-boy-advance

I am Programming on Mac OS X 10.6 with XCode. Im trying to make a Programm that "decrypts" a Pokemon GBA game so that you can read the dialogs of the game with any Text Editor.

I already got a programm finished witch does that, so I can read all Text Data.

My problem is, that I need to change the clear Text back to Hex after editing it, but I have no Idea what im making wrong.

```
string PathDE;
string PathGBA;
string Zeichen;
int kontrolle = 0;
int current = 0;

char buffer1[3] = "00";
char buffer2[3] = "a1";
...

schreiben.open(PathGBA.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary); //writes out the edited hex
lesen.open(PathDE.c_str(), ios::in); //reads in the plain text


while(current <= kontrolle){
    lesen.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), 1);
    converter << a;
    converter >> Zeichen;
    if(Zeichen == "_"){
        schreiben.write(buffer1,3);
    }
    else if(Zeichen == "0"){
        schreiben.write(buffer2,3);
    }
...
```

I Tryed that, but when I open the result in a Hex Editor, the ASCII code is only a8.a8.a8.a8... and so on till eof, and the Hex code is 61 38 00 ... till eof.

I also tryed other methods, but all with the same result, I cant write the decoded GBA as Hex so I can play it with edited Text.

Comment: You want it to be a8a8a8 ? or a8 a8 a8 a8 instead of a8.a8.a8

Comment: No i dont want it to be a8 a8 a8. I want to translate the content of a Text file like this: http://magicstone.de/rhw/files/andere/Rubylat.tbl

Comment: You want it to be 00 00 00 or 00000000

Comment: If the Text is "Hello there" i want it to be C2 D9 E0 E0 E3 00 E8 DC D9 E6 D9

Comment: I really need this cause no answer i found on google helped me out of this. I need to convert the content of a .txt file to hex and write it with ios::binary out into another file.

Comment: Are you reading binary, converting to hex-strings and now want to go back to binary? Or are you reading binary and can't write out the hex-strings? Aside from the fact that your code is in German, there's a lot of context missing, which could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to convert your string into a byte[] with the correct encoding.
Here is the Gen3 text table for Pokemon
http://datacrystal.romhacking.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_FireRed_-_TBL

Once converted correctly you will simply just insert it into your rom.

Sorry if this doesnt help much but I only have made c# Pokemon tools, not c++.

And btw pokemon doesnt use a ascii hex encryption it uses a form of utf8.